# Spring Boot Primitive Rest Controller Returns Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to build & run my Spring boot project which returns "I am alive" on the page. I have basic main class and one rest controller class. I guess solution is simple but i couldnt find any question similar with me.

Here is the thing.

## Main Class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

## Rest Controller

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HealthCheck {

    @GetMapping("/up")
    public String checkHealth(){
        return "I am alive";
    }
}
```

When i go to localhost:8080/up, it returns as

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Sep 25 17:47:53 EEST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

## POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Yeah i've edited this already

Comment: The logs must contain somewhere the error info (the one you posted does not). Can you check the logs again and post it here with the errors?

Comment: There is no error in the tracelog. All i have is mentioned above in the yellow area

Comment: There is noting on the application.properties file. Is this a problem?

Comment: Nothing in the application.properties shouldn't be a problem since SB uses the default values

Comment: In what package is your controller ? Is it in the same or a sub-package of your main class?

Comment: I have just shared a picture

Comment: You need to either fix the project structure or use `@ComponentScan`. Check **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52155110/5640649)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot will scan for classes annotated with `@RestController` starting from the package that the main class (the one with `@SpringBootApplication`) and below. The easiest fix is to move your controller to the same package or a sub package of where your main class lives.

Comment: Your solution definitely fix the above problem. But sometimes you structure of your project does not allow main Application and controller(s) to live under one package.

Comment: I would even say that most of the time this is not the case. But in all Spring Boot projects I have seen, they live in a subpackage. I personally prefer to package by feature. So if my main is in `com.mycompany.myapp` then my `OrderController` would be in `com.mycompany.myapp.order.web`. If your main class is in `com.mycompany.myapp`, then everything will work by default.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Its all about structuring the folders.

Comment: Heyy Wim 
Thank you very much u have savedd my lots of hours.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `@GetMapping("/up")` try using `@RequestMapping("/up")`. As you want to see the message on the page, `RequestMapping` returns plain text when requested using either a browser or curl on the command line.

Comment: SpringBootApplication annotation can be used to enable those three features, that is:

EnableAutoConfiguration: enable Spring Boot’s auto-configuration mechanism
ComponentScan: enable Component scan on the package where the application is located (see the best practices)
Configuration: allow to register extra beans in the context or import additional configuration classes


So i dont think you are missing any annotation in the Main class @Berkin

Comment: i guess @GetMapping means @RequestMapping(value = "/up", method = RequestMethod.GET) and i was suggesting @RequestMapping("/up") 
so that it will  resolve all the http request i.e. you can send GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, TRACE

Comment: Ah, you are right. If you don't specify a `method` with `@RequestMapping` than all methods can be used. But I would not recommend this. When you are just typing a URL in a browser, you will be using `GET` anyway.

Comment: I had ran into similar problem once so just thought it might help :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Spring doesn't see your controller. You have to use `@ComponentScan`

```
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class FraudWsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FraudWsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

You can also find an example in my [repo](https://github.com/dehasi/scc_gp/blob/master/src/main/java/me/dehasi/contracts/demo/SccDemoApplication.java)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I&#39;ll try it tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Adding `@ComponentScan` like this will not help. It would help if you add the package name where the controller lives, but the more straightforward and recommended solution is to move the controller to a subpackage of your main class.

Answer (score 0):

In your main `Application` change annotation to `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.ykb.frd"})`