# SpringBoot JPA @Autowired no bean found exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, autowired

Edited to add proc structure:

main/java
   hello(package)
     Application(main app)
     TestRestController
   models(package)
     Test
   services(package)
     TestRepo(interface)

I'm currently looking at component scan as just released the 'repo.Test' in the exception is a clue.

I've been through numerous tutorials and questions and still cannot find the answer to my particular issue, which is most likely to be down to my lack of understanding.

I have a spring boot application that I'm adding a db to.  I've been following this tutorial : https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/

However when I try and run my application (following identical steps) I get an exception:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repo.TestRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

I do have another bean autowired in, the main difference is that this bean(the one that works) has a service that implements the interface and a bean configuration class.  None of the examples for JPA follow that model and it seems daft to create a service to re-implement the methods from the JPARepo.

This is the controller I'm using:

```
    @RestController
public class TestRestController {

    @Autowired
    GreetingService greetingService;

    @Autowired
    TestRepo testRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String home() {
        return greetingService.greet();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/testrepo")
        public String testrepo() {

        Test test = new Test("steve");

        testRepo.save(test);
        Long idOftest = test.getId();

        test = null;
        test = testRepo.findById(idOftest).get();

        return "DID THIS WORK::::: + "+ test.toString();
    }
```

with the interface being

```
    @Repository
public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<Test, Long> {
}
```

and the model:

```
    @Entity
@Data
public class Test {

    private final String name;

    public Test(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

The application main is:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

//    @Bean
//    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx ) {
//        return args -> {
//
//            System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");
//
//            String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
//            Arrays.sort(beanNames);
//            for (String beanName : beanNames) {
//                System.out.println(beanName);
//            }
//
//
//        };
//    }


}
```

I recently commented out the bean annotation to see if that was causing an issue.

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: can you post the structure of your project? Specifically where in the package three are located files `TestRepo` class and the main class (the one which holds the `main` method)?

Comment: Please post the package structure of your project of your project

Comment: See this answer which addresses the exact same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154652/intellij-springboot-problems-on-startup/52155110#52155110

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij Springboot problems on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154652/intellij-springboot-problems-on-startup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this exception because your class `TestRepo` is part of `repo` package, which is not the sub-package hierarchy of `Application` class package. `@SpringBootApplication` defines an automatic component scan on the packages which are subpackages of your main class i.e `Application`. If you want to resolve this issue without changing your package hierarchy add below line with `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
@ComponentScan({"repo","your.application.class.package"}) //// add the names of the packages where the controllers, services, repositories beans are stored
```

Comment: ah! that now makes sense.  So a solution is to either, move application up and do some refactoring of the structure (not a massive deal at this stage but feels tacky) or ask Spring to scan the 'other' packages?

Comment: Yes. @SpringBootApplication only scans the sub packages of your main class package

Comment: when trying to use your example, it doesn't allow me to use a string as part of the annotation and when remove the quotes it tells me it must be a constant clue - not sure which is the correct approach

Comment: and thank you for taking the time to comment / explain / help - very kind of you

Comment: thank you!  I corrected a couple of issues and we're now rocking and rolling :D