# How to fix "Field ... required a bean of type ... that could not be found" exception Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I am working with spring boot tutorial from *javabrains* and everything was clear until putting `CrudRepository` inside project. Below you can find my main class:

```
package pl.springBootStarter.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiDataApplication
{
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    SpringApplication.run(CourseApiDataApplication.class,args);
}
}
```

Service class:

```
package pl.springBootStarter.app.topic;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TopicService
{
    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;

    private List<Topic> topics =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Topic("spring","spring framework", "spring framework dectription"),
            new Topic("sprin","spring framework", "spring framework dectription"),
            new Topic("spri","spring framework", "spring framework dectription")));

    public  List<Topic> getAllTopics()
    {
    //    return topics;
    List<Topic> t = new ArrayList<Topic>();
    topicRepository.findAll().forEach(t::add);
    return t;
    }

    public Topic getTopic (String id)
    {
        return   topics.stream().filter( t -> t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
    }

    public void addTopic(Topic topic) {
        topicRepository.save(topic);
    }

    public void updateTopic(Topic topic, String id)
    {
        topics.set(topics.indexOf(topics.stream().filter(t-> t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get()), topic);
    }

    public void deleteTopic(String id)
    {
        topics.remove(topics.stream().filter(t -> t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get());
    }
}
```

And `Repository` interface:

```
package pl.springBootStarter.app.topic;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic,String>
{

}
```

When I run the app there is a problem with injection of `TopicRepository` into `topicRepository` field in `TopicService` class. I get following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-       run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-05-01 10:33:52.206 ERROR 6972 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field topicRepository in pl.springBootStarter.app.topic.TopicService required a bean of type 'pl.springBootStarter.app.topic.TopicRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
-    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

What could be the reason that Spring cannot do the autowiring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Be sure the class is scanned by spring!**

(this may help if that's the problem:
[Intellij Springboot problems on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154652/intellij-springboot-problems-on-startup/52155110#52155110)).

---

Optionally you may want to annotate `TopicRepository` as a [`@Repository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html).

```
@Repository
public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic,String>
{
}
```

See a demo code here: https://github.com/lealceldeiro/repository-demo

Comment: @Elrok do you have a repository in which I can take a look? This is supposed to work. I've used it myself a lot of times. Did you make sure spring is detecting the `TopicRepository`  class and registering as a bean??

Comment: In my project there are only 4 classes:

 CourseApiDataApplication
 TopicRepository
 TopicService
 Topic - the class that contains fields, getters and setters.

Comment: I am quite new to Spring. How to make sure that spring is detecting TopicRepository class and registering as a bean?

Comment: I am sure that the problem in my app is that Spring does not find TopicRepository class as a bean. So it does not know what shall be injected in topicRepository field in class TopicService.

Comment: @Elrok see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154652/intellij-springboot-problems-on-startup/52155110#52155110 I'm creating a demo for you... give some minutes

Answer (score 3):

Spring cannot inject bean because it has not been created.

You have to instruct Spring to generate implementation of declared repository interfaces by using `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"pl.springBootStarter.app"})` annotation on any of your configuration classes or class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: I put this in my main class and now I have another exception:


Field topicRepository in pl.springBootStarter.app.topic.TopicService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

      The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Comment: seems like you haven't configured persistence context, can you post your config file?

Comment: The solution from @lealceldeiro worked perfectly. I had to put @ComponentScan("packageName") form my package, where I had my Service Repository and Controler classes. Dziękuję za zainteresowanie tematem.

Comment: I put this, and I messed the routes, appears to me with an error 404

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar message and I was missing the @Service annotation in the Service class. Simple mistake, posting in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who was brought here by googling the generic bean error message, but who is actually trying to add a ***feign client*** to their Spring Boot application via the `@FeignClient` annotation on your client interface, none of the above solutions will work for you.

To fix the problem, you need to add the `@EnableFeignClients` annotation to your Application class, like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
// ... (other pre-existing annotations) ...
@EnableFeignClients // <------- THE IMPORTANT ONE
public class Application {
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar message.

the thing was my main package was **com.example**
and the package for other classes was **com.xyz**

so when I **Changed** the name of the package of other class to **com.example.topic**

i.e.
finally
The main package was **com.example**
and the package for the other class was **com.example.topic**

A simple mistake, posting in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, the necessary configuration from `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.` has been excluded at SpringBootApplication, causing relevant bean not added properly. Check your main application java file and see if you can find following configuration in the exclusion list

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,                      // REMOVE THIS
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,    // REMOVE THIS
    }
)
```

and remove them from exclusion list.

Answer (score 0):

in service class
do:
@Autowired(required=false)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).